# Making data in an XML not able to be edited via a text editor

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, xna

I'm currently following a tutorial series for a Tile Engine which uses XML files to store conversations between NPCs. A topic it doesn't appear to cover (I have only quickly glanced through the subsequent videos) is how to prevent the user from either altering or knowing in advance what the NPC is going to say by opening the XML file easily with a generic text editor.

The 2nd point of being able to read future conversations is not a real issue but something I wanted to think about, so if that's hard to implement I am not too fussed at this point.

How would I go about making the XML uneditable? I know vaguely about CRC32's which can check file integrity which may be useful and I also think there *might* be better ways to go about that (i.e. not with a CRC32).

The most extreme action I can think of would be to create my own arbitrary encoding for the conversation data, but the usefulness of XML files deters me from that slightly, and with the tutorials I'm following teaching me a lot things I don't know, I would prefer not to defer too far away from them!

Just looking for a direction really, thanks!

Comment: Encrypt your files using RSA encryption?

Comment: And what about Binary serialization of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Historically, many games wrap multiple resources into a single binary file.

You might put it in a ZIP file (and maybe change the file extension).  That would allow you to avoid having an XML file with an obvious name as a temptation for your users :).

Ultimately, you're asking something similar to the DRM question.  I don't know whether your platform has an answer to that.  (E.g., "using RSA encryption" is not *secure* as such; your program still has to decrypt the data at some point using the appropriate key, etc).

Comment: This is probably more along the lines of what I wanted, how would you go about having this kind of content file? Would I need to make a content importer? How would I be able to access the files individually from within VS?

Comment: The ZIP would be generated as part of the build process.

Comment: So you'd just edit the individual source file(s) as normal.  XNA probably has integrated support for something like this (not necessarily ZIP), but that's where my knowledge comes to an end, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Xml is in its fundamentals an open format, so I mean there is not way how to make xml uneditable.

But you can have a copy of xml document (or some of fingerprint of xml) on your server (or on endpoints of NPC conversation) and then you can compare if xml document was edited or no.

If document was edited, you cas replace it with backup version or say to endpoints, that xml document was corrupted...